# Complex SQL PIVOT with log data

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

[image: Here]

I have this two tables at my db , as you see they have 1->N relation.
it's a log for each participant that answers questionnaire at a unique date,
at each date the participant can answer 3 questionnaires M(Morning) N(Noon) E(Evening), and each questionnaire contains question that are numbered (1,2,3..)
Note: the unique key for participant is participantid ignore the research and group ids
the result a I need is:

[image: Here]

As you see each questionnaire can be with different number of questions (the morning ques. contains 4 ,the noon ques. contains 3 and the evening ques. contains 2).

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: MySQL is not the right tool for this. You need a reporting framework; you can always export to spreadsheet though and then do the pivoting.

Comment: @Jayvee can you please send some guide or something?

Comment: Some tasks are better done in PHP (or other application language) than in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use row data and convert them into columns (pivot), i.e every date/time/question will be a column in your desired output.

This normally is difficult to do in SQL, if not impossible, when the data you are pivoting is not constant or enumerable.

What you need to do in these cases is access the data from a reporting layer and do the pivoting at report level, as you could do in SSRS or Qlikview for instance.

If you don't have a reporting layer, as I said on the comments, you can always download the data to spreadsheet and create the pivot table. If you need to know how to pivot in Excel, you can do a search on the web and you will find many tutorials, for example this one:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Quick-start-Create-a-PivotTable-report-0c220f35-e478-49aa-beaf-24018b7f0f64

You can also use other spreadsheet software like LibreOffice to create Pivot tables as well:

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Creating_Pivot_Tables